# Debugging basics

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, xcode6

I'm new in programming, and I'm trying to code my first app in swift.
I've got my App crashing at runtime, but I'm not able to understand a word in Xcode debug navigator.
I can't post a screenshot as this is my first post at StackOverFlow.

Could you help me to interpret XCode6 (Swift) crash console.
How can I point toward the cause of a crash?
What do I have to focus on ?

Sorry for this general question but I was not able to find some clear documentation on debugging in XCode 6.

Thanks for your help

Here is what the console displays (after removing the breakpoint) :

> (Entrée dans la fonction, numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la
>   fonction, tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la
>   fonction, numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) 2015-04-14 12:05:12.659
>   ListeDeCourses[20984:2203737] -[ListeDeCourses.AjoutViewController
>   ButtonAdd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe178739770
>   2015-04-14 12:05:12.663 ListeDeCourses[20984:2203737] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[ListeDeCourses.AjoutViewController ButtonAdd:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fe178739770'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ecff35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000108a13bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000106ed704d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e2f27c
>   ___forwarding_** + 988    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e2ee18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x000000010775c8be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>     6   UIKit                               0x0000000107863410
>   -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467   7   UIKit                               0x00000001078627df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522   8
>   UIKit                               0x00000001077a2308 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735  9   UIKit                               0x00000001077a2c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683     10  UIKit
>   0x000000010776f9b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246  11  UIKit
>   0x000000010777ca7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370    12
>   UIKit                               0x0000000107758103
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961     13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e05551
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106dfb41d
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269   15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106dfaa54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868     16  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000106dfa486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     17  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010afc69f0 GSEventRunModal + 161  18  UIKit
>   0x000000010775b420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   19  ListeDeCourses
>   0x0000000106ce243e top_level_code + 78    20  ListeDeCourses
>   0x0000000106ce247a main + 42  21  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001091ed145 start + 1  22  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

and this is what is displayed with an exception breakpoint :

> (Entrée dans la fonction, numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la
>   fonction, tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la
>   fonction, numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   numberOfSectionsInTableView) (Entrée dans la fonction,
>   tableView(*:numberOfRowsInSection:)) 2015-04-14 12:10:28.285
>   ListeDeCourses[21044:2208020] -[ListeDeCourses.AjoutViewController
>   ButtonAdd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf5a748630
>   (lldb)

Finally a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you build for debugging (top left Project Name/Edit Scheme). Open the breakpoint tab left (the thick arrow pointing right). Click the plus symbol. Add exception breakpoint. Run again

Comment: Many thanks Thomas. It helps. I have proceeded as you told me. The apps still crashes, and I still don't know which part of my code is wrong. What is the use of the break point ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is shown by

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ListeDeCourses.AjoutViewController ButtonAdd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe178739770

Means that you send an unknown message `ButtonAdd:` to a controller. With the breakpoint set your code will stop at the relevant position and you should be able to spot the reason.

Comment: thanks Thomas. But with the breakpoint set, Xcode still stop somewhere in the assembly code.

0x108a4a430:  movl   %ecx, %edi
0x108a4a432:  movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rsi
0x108a4a436:  movq   %rax, %rcx
0x108a4a439:  callq  0x108a4ca0e               ; symbol stub for: UIApplicationMain
0x108a4a43e:  movl   %eax, -0x1c(%rbp)
0x108a4a441:  addq   $0x20, %rsp
0x108a4a445:  popq   %rbp
0x108a4a446:  retq

Comment: The trace on the left (see @HoaParis answer) will let you step back in the call stack until you find the offending code in your source.

Comment: OK, but whatever the call I select within the call stack, I still have that kind of assembly code on the right. Even If I step back to the most downstream call. (Which is 17UIApplicationMain) - 

The very top line of the thread is named "0 objc_exception_throw"
When I select it, I still get this assembly code - 

Sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: Can you place a screenshot on a public server and post the link?

Comment: That looks quite like you created the whole project wrong. You should start over with a blank project and incrementally add what you tried to do until it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you debug your application with Xcode, if application crash, XCode will stop at the line that it crashes. You can see then what happens in the "Debug navigator"

[image]

And the console:

[image]

If the console does not appear, press on the button on the left of the blue button in this image to show it. This bar button is on the bottom of your XCode.

[image]

If XCode does not stop at the exception point, try to add Exception breakpoint in breakpoint menu:

[image]

Comment: thanks HoaParis ! My problem is that on the right part, I don't get the part of my code that makes my app crashing. Instead, I've got what looks like a list of memory addresses which I'm not able to understand...

Comment: Show those errors in your question so we can know what are those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found in StackOverFlow that I needed to uncheck an option : Debug > Debug > Always show disassembly.
Thanks to all for helping me to find the good keywords in my search.